# HA-Proxy errors in configuration file

Tags: haproxy, apache2, varnish

Below is the configuration file for my haproxy in which i want to setup the varnish as backend & in frontend want to configure the Port-80 for http & for the port-443 for https

global
log /dev/log    local0
log /dev/log    local1 notice
chroot /var/lib/haproxy
stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
stats timeout 30s
user haproxy
group haproxy
daemon

```
# Default SSL material locations
ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
crt-base /etc/ssl/private

# See: https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=haproxy&server-version=2.0.3&config=intermediate
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
```

defaults
log global
mode    http
option  httplog
option  dontlognull
timeout connect 5000
timeout client  50000
timeout server  50000
errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend www-http
bind *:80

```
#redirect to HTTPS if ssl_fc is false / off.
redirect scheme https if !{ssl_fc}
default_backend varnish_backend
```

frontend www-https
bind *:443 ssl /etc/letsencrypt/live/r2m.pixelmechanics.de/cert.pem
acl secure dst_port eq 443
http-response replace-header Set-Cookie (.*) \1;\ Secure
http-request set-header "SSL-OFFLOADED" "1"
default_backend varnish_backend

backend varnish_backend
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
server r2m-web-prod 45.12.51.173:8080 check
Can anyone help me in this that would be great my job is in danger mode.

now below error which i am getting that is this
[ALERT] 070/121406 (151885) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:39] : error detected in frontend 'www-http' while parsing redirect rule : error in condition: no such ACL : '{ssl_fc}'.
[ALERT] 070/121406 (151885) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:43] : 'bind *:443' unknown keyword '/etc/letsencrypt/live/r2m.pixelmechanics.de/cert.pem'. Registered keywords :

Answer (score 1):

1. change `{ssl_fc}` to `{ ssl_fc }` - those spaces are required
2. you need `crt` keyword between `ssl` and cert path, e.g.

```
     bind *:443 ssl crt /path/to/cert
```

P.S. I edited your post to fix formatting for readability, but someone else still has approve it.

Comment: Thanks tbielaszewski for the assistance it has been figured out now.